# How does a pair of Jack's beat pair kings

Tags: texas-hold-em

Was playing Texas Hold Em and I had a king and 7. I believe there was a king showing after the river, I made my bet then my opponent called me on it he had 2 jacks in his hand he won the pot.. How is that??

Comment: Going to close this as it's a duplicate of the above, and also there is a lack of details on the board, and an uncertainty of what the river was. As a suggestion you should post the full board, flop, turn and river on these type of questions with the suits. It's likely in this case the jacks had something more than just 2 jacks if you lost.

Comment: Perhaps the board was 9-10-Q-K-2, and his jack made a straight. Perhaps the board had four diamonds and his Jack of diamonds made a flush (and your king was not a diamond).